# .match returns null on trying to match a regular expression that is correct and has a match

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have been stuck trying to figure out why my JavaScript code that is supposed to return a match for a regular expression returns null.

I am basically trying to get the date from a google calendar feed using regex and I have tested the regex and its working fine in regexpal.com.

Here is my code:

```
var eventTextDate = String(value.summary);
var patt1 = /([A-Z][a-z]{2} ){2}\d+, \d+ \d+:\d+.m/;
var eventDate = eventTextDate.match(patt1);
```

value.summary equals the following:

```
When: Tue Jan 21, 2014 1:30pm to 3pm 
GMT&lt;br /&gt;
```

Note the newline and forward slashes. I thought they might have something to do with it so I tried to substring(5,30) the string to get rid of the slashes and newlines but that didn't seem to help.

Also, if I change the regex to something like /.../ it does return the three first letter. So I know the basic mechanism and structure of my code works.

I guess my regular expression has some error (even though it works on regexpal.com) as I am new to regex.

I would really appreciate any help or tips for me regarding this issue.

Comment: What is the input, and what output to you want to produce?

Comment: I get the input from an ajax response (xml document).
I get the value object by performing a $.each loop over the ajax response object. Each value object contains a title, some other data and a summary, which contains the date.
I want to use a regular expression to extract the date from the summary.

Comment: Why so complicated? When you simply want to extract the date why not use `When:\s(.*)\s`? This would give you the whole date-string in the first capturing group.

Comment: thanks for that Basti M, it seems to work. However now I get the match printed out twice with a space and a comma separating them. Very strange.Plus I don't need the part after the first time, as in I don't need the ' to 3pm' part.

Comment: This isn't a strange behaviour. This is the match-array. I suggest you read the [MDN doc on regexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions#Working_with_Regular_Expressions) and especially the [MDN doc on `match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fmatch). Remember: what you match isn't what you capture!

Comment: Thanks! How do I mark this as solved?

Comment: Just posted my comments as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
When:\s(.*)\s
```

as your regular expression.
The date-string will then be in the frist capturing group, accessible as the second index of the [match-array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Working_with_Regular_Expressions), for example:

```
var re = /When:\s(.*)\s/; 
var str = 'When: Tue Jan 21, 2014 1:30pm to 3pm\nGMT&lt;br /&gt;';
var m = str.match(re);

alert(m[1]);
```

If you don't need the `to 3pm` part, then modify the regex to

```
When:\s(.*)\sto
```